# Dúvida com layouts dinâmicos

Tags: php, estilo-de-codificação

Costumo montar as views's das aplicações php que utilizo com operadores condicionais.

Por exemplo, usuário não logado, seto uma variável inicial na sessão:

```
$logado = FALSE;
```

Caso o usuário esteja logado, atribuo `TRUE` e dentro das view's, torno algumas coisas dinâmicas, por exemplo, o botão de login.

```
if (!$logado) {
    //exibe formulário de login
} else {
    //Exibe mensagem: bem vindo user xxxx, clique aqui para efetuar logoff.
}
```

E utilizo isto em outras coisas também, por exemplo, usuário logado, pode salvar uma nova informação em um form, usuário não logado, apenas visualiza o resultado do select de informações já salvas.

A minha dúvida é: Isto é uma boa prática?

Utilizar `if` no contexto de estruturar o html e torná-lo adaptável de acordo com variáveis setadas em sessão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gerar *views* dinâmicas, de acordo com determinados parâmetros, é um desafio em qualquer linguagem.

Há basicamente três abordagens principais para lidar com isso:

## Scripts

A abordagem de misturar scripts com HTML é a mais eficiente, porém pode facilmente levar a código difícil de entender, dar manutenção e propenso a erros.

## *Template Engines*

Usar um mecanismo de *templates* ajuda a separar lógica da apresentação. O efeito colateral é o desempenho, já que os *templates* precisam ser interpretados para gerar a saída.

Alguns mecanismos permitem a "compilação" dos *templates* para resolver o problema do desempenho, mas isso exigirá um cuidado a mais na implementação.

Particularmente eu gosto da abordagem baseada em *templates*.

## Componentes

Alguns frameworks geram as views através de componentes, que na verdade são uma coleção de objetos que encapsulam o HTML gerado.

Em PHP isso não é tão comum quanto em Java, por exemplo, mas se me lembro bem o Yii funciona dessa maneira.

A vantagem é que há um algo grau de reaproveitamento de código, mas devido à grande abstração e complexidade você pode facilmente perder o controle do que está fazendo, além de tornar tarefas que outrora seriam triviais em algo que depende de um conhecimento relativamente profundo do framework.

## Considerações

Não há nenhum problema em usar alguns `ifs` ou laços no código, desde que você consiga fazer a separação disso com a lógica do sistema.

Um exemplo bem simples de como usar a própria linguagem PHP como um tipo de *template engine*, evitando assim a grande quantidade de classes incluídas ao se usar frameworks, pode ser visto em alguns *templates* do Wordpress. Exemplo:

```php
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>    
    <!-- do stuff ... -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```